# Book/Reference on LEAPs/ Long dated options

Tags: options, reference-request

Can anyone suggest a book on pricing and trading in LEAPs / Long dated options (maturity atleast 6 months )or a generic book which covers this topic in great detail.

I’m specifically looking at how rho and theta for these options are different from short dated ones and how I need to consider that.

I found a couple good articles but they seem to be about hedging and not really speculative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Not *really* pricing focused, but have you looked at: [Marc Allaire and Marty Kearney. *Understanding Leaps: Using the Most Effective Option Strategies for Maximum Advantage.* McGraw-Hill 2002.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071383867)

2 an article on the rho of long-dated commodity options, rather than equity options https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/fut.21954

3 [Gurdip Bakshi, Charles Cao, Zhiwu Chen. Pricing and hedging long-term options.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407699000238)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful